Uniqueness of automorphism that preserves field and maps conjugate elements
I've came across this question, it is an exercise from Abstract Algebra book. The original question was closed, so I have to ask here.
Let's repeat it: $F$ is a field, $\alpha \in F, \beta \in F$ are cojugate elements, $\beta \in F(\alpha).$ Prove that there is only one unique automorphism $\phi: F(\alpha) \to F(\alpha)$ that preserves $F$ and $\phi(\alpha) = \beta$.
The problem is that I do not understand how the fact that $\alpha, \beta$ are conjugate is used. It seems natural to set $\phi : \frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)} \to \frac{f(\beta)}{g(\beta)}$, because $F(\alpha)$ is a set of natural functions.
Let's look at $\phi$: it's clearly homomorphism, $\phi(\frac{\alpha}{1}) = \frac{\beta}{1}$, it preserves $F$ because constants are zero polynomials. It's surjective by definition, and it's kernel is trivial. Am I right in assuming that conjugation of $\alpha, \beta$ is used to show that kernel is trivial, hence it is injective? I'm really trying to understand it completely and it seems like I'm missing something.
I'm sorry if I had to ask this question in a linked post (it is closed so I decided to create new question), I'd be very grateful for your help

The condition that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are conjugate is used to ensure that your map $\phi$ is well-defined.

@Piyo, how do you use this condition? suppose we have $\frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)} = \frac{h(\alpha)}{q(\alpha)}$, then we apply $\phi$ for both parts and get: $\frac{f(\beta)}{g(\beta)}$ and $\frac{h(\beta)}{q(\beta)}$. how can we use conjugation to conclude that images are equal?

Let $p(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$, that is, $p\in F[x]$ is the monic polynomial over $F$ of minimal degree such that $p(\alpha)=0$. Then you have to check that $\phi(p(\alpha))=0$. See also Mark’s answer.

It may be helpful to consider an example where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not conjugate. For example, you cannot make any map $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)\to\mathbb Q(\sqrt3)$ with $\sqrt2\mapsto\sqrt3$.

@Piyo, yes, I've read Mark's answer in the linked post but I'm not sure that I understand his idea with isomorphism.. Firstly, I just want to completely understand the post I wrote = )
Speaking of your answer: why is it enough to check that $\phi(p(\alpha)) = 0$ to prove that $\phi$ is well-defined? We prove that something is well defined this way: let $a_1 = a_2$ let's prove that $\phi(a_1) = \phi(a_2)$. What am I missing here? Thanks for your patience

I apologize for the delayed response. Checking that $\phi(p(\alpha))=0$ aligns with the well-definedness you mentioned. Since we have $p(\alpha)=0$, it is necessary that $\phi(p(\alpha))=\phi(0) = 0$.

A more precise argument: We have an isomorphism $F(\alpha)\simeq F[x]/(p)$ of rings, that is, $F(\alpha)$ is the quotient ring of the polynomial ring $F[x]$ by the ideal generated by the minimal polynomial $p(x)$ (as explained in Mark’s answer). To construct $\phi$, we first consider the map$$\phi_0\colon F[x]\to F(\alpha),\quad x\mapsto\beta.$$Then we need to check $\phi_0(p)=0$ to show that $\phi_0$ factors through $F[x]/(p)$ (this is the universality of quotient rings), i.e., $\phi_0$ induces the desired map $\phi\colon F(\alpha)\to F(\alpha)$. This argument is the well-definedness I wrote.
